# Different render result from Blender 2.90.1 to 3.4.1

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, versions

I tried to find this out myself by comparing settings and googling, but I failed so far.

Opening an old project, that needs continuous work, renders differently in a newer Blender version. I know, there was a big jump from 2.x to 3.x in cycles, but could anybody give me a hint how to make it render as before? (Because the new rendering is splotchy with really bad shadows.)

Opening my file in 2.90.1 leads to this (which is good):
[image]

Opening the same file in 3.4.1 leads to this:
[image]

No changes made, just hit <kbd>F12</kbd>...

You see, the newer rendering is darker with really bad shadows.

If anyone has any tips for me I would appreciate.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: Cycles for 2.93 or below has been changed internally from 3.0, the Code was Cycles X, now known just as Cycles [HERE](https://code.blender.org/2021/04/cycles-x/). So, the same settings from 2.93 could make the scene looks different

Comment: It is probably sample count and noise threshold + denoiser settings in the render panel.  Disabling noise threshold completely is probably closer to your previous renders

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. Unfortunately it´s not sample count, noise threshold or denoiser. Of course these settings have some impact - but they do not significantly move it towards the old result. I wasn´t able to get the 3.4.1 result close to 2.90.1 in any way. Maybe it´s because of my rather unusual setup, I have to investigate this further - but I´m lacking of time.

If anyone comes up with ideas I would appreciate. If I get some enlightment I will share it.